# Finding specific argument then adding value of next one to variable

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line-arguments

I'm new to java and i need some help. I got few things to do and i'm stuck
with this problem. I really have no idea how to do it...

So in CMD line if i enter banana banana apple apple -name Carlos banana Mike -c 8
it will print "Hello Carlos!" eight times.

```
public class cheese {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        for(String s: args){
             if(s.equals("-name")){
                 String p = (GIVE VALUE OF FIRST ARGUMENT AFTER "-name");
                 if (s.equals("-c")){
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(THE FIRST ARGUMENTS AFTER "-c");
                    for(int j=0; j >= i ; j++)
                    System.out.println("Hello "+p+"!");
                }
             }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is much better to use a `Scanner` than get your input through command-line arguments.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: what's exactly your question?

Comment: Oh... Well, it's in the code :) When i find specific command line argument how do i add first next value to my variable if number of arguments inputed by user is random.

Comment: I hope you understand me.... iterate through args, find keyword "-name" then add 1st argument next to it to my String name, and find "-c" and add 1st thing after it to my int i...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing command-line arguments properly is surprisingly hard, and there are lots of libraries that can help. Your example code can be rearranged as follows to make it work (but it has no real error handling, so there are lots of ways to make it go wrong, such as passing "-name" twice, or not supplying enough arguments).

```
public class CmdLine {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String p = "";
        int i = 0;

        for (int k = 0; k < args.length; k++) {
            if (args[k].equals("-name")) {
                p = args[k + 1];
            } else if (args[k].equals("-c")) {
                i = Integer.parseInt(args[k + 1]);
            }
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            System.out.println("Hello " + p + "!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, i'm going with assumption that user wont do that. And you sir, are my hero :) <3 This is what i need :)